# Warranty on server grade hard-disks. Is that a good thing?

Tags: hard-drive, nas, warranty

I couldn't come up with a better question and I hope this does not belong to server fault.

Recently I obtained some western digital RED hard-disks, which are specially build for NAS.

They come with an extended warranty, but any warranty action requires the hard disk to be sent to the manufacturer.

Neither as a private user, nor as a company does this sound appealing, or am I wrong?

Assuming the disk is part of a redundant raid, so you won't need any data recovery I would just not feel good by any means to send a non-encrypted disk with private or company data to any company (this is not limited to WD, Samsung, etc.)

I made the observation that full disk encryption is not common in companies as such NAS disks are used internally only. And encryption is even less common for home users.

Do such disaster scenarios not simply imply buying another disk and ignoring the warranty to prevent sending data across the world? 
I mean if I could safely erase data on the disk I probably could still access it properly, and safely killing it with some force would *probably* void the warranty :D

Comment: You cannot clear a disk that you cannot access, if the data is so valuable then the money to buy a new one is nothing. any storage of say 1T of data or more generally the data is more valuable than the media it is placed on. Read the warrenty, they usually do not include any intention to recover data, nor replacing it with a New disk. Even tested I am not sure I want someone elses returned drive. I want the drive to be supported & warrentied, but if the warrenty does not cover a new drive, I will still buy a new one. I treat my drives like glass.